# Unable To start download

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am automating the downloading of a report but am struggling getting the report to run. When manually carrying out process I navigate to report area and right click "run as excel"

When I inspect the element I have the below lines which I cannot get to run in my code.
[Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVXXN.jpg)

I have tried .click on a few of the different ID's ("ext-gen152") or ("ext-gen153") but I think I need to approach executing this line different due to it not being a visible button but a hidden menu.

If this is simple and been covered before accept my apologies but a point in the right direction would be handed. Is there a really good resource vba with IE?

I have also tried looping through the elements in an object but do not know the name of the object which "ext-gen152" sits

```
Sub AP_Login()

Dim Site As Object
Set Site = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

Dim AP_ID As String
Dim AP_PW As String
Dim URL As String
Dim ControlSht As Worksheet
Dim Obj As Object

Site.Visible = True
Set ControlSht = Sheet2

AP_ID = ControlSht.Range("user").Value
AP_PW = ControlSht.Range("Password").Value
URL = ControlSht.Range("LogPage").Value

Site.Navigate URL
While Site.Busy
Wend

Dim oHTMLDoc As Object
Set oHTMLDoc = Site.Document

oHTMLDoc.getElementById("inputEmail").Value = AP_ID
oHTMLDoc.getElementById("inputPassword").Value = AP_PW
oHTMLDoc.getElementById("submit").Click

While Site.Busy
Wend

URL = ControlSht.Range("ReportPage").Value  

Site.Navigate URL
While Site.Busy
Wend


oHTMLDoc.getElementById("ext-gen153").Click



Site.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Xarxziux, what should I tag the JPEG attached to the elements link in my text. What language is this?

Comment: That's HTML, not JavaScript!

Comment: Not looking hopefully.